# Updating Approved timecards in future method

Tags: trigger

We have a requirement where hours are charged to a timecard(main timecard) that has a project 'Y'of project type 'X'. When this timecard is approved the hours from this timecard are distributed to active milestones of all the child projects of this 'Y' by creating timecards.

I have a timecard trigger(After update) on the Timecard Header that hands this timecard with project 'Y' to a future method. The future method does the time distribution.

When time is succesfully distributed, a custom field 'Allocated__c' is set to true on the main timecard and an upsert statement on the main timecard is executed.
When me (System Administrator) approves the timecard, timecard gets approved and the future  method is executed and allocated__c field is updated correctly
When a manager(not a system administrator but user who is authorized to approve by the approval process) approves the timecard, the timecard is approved, but when the future method sets allocated__c, the upsert statements fails with the following error.

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 6 with id a9G36000000K8UwEAK; first error: ENTITY_IS_LOCKED, the entity is locked for editing: []

Based on [this help link](http://help.financialforce.com/psa/15X/Default.htm#topics/OpsEditPermissionControl.htm?Highlight=whitelist), I see that OPs Edit permission control is needed to edit an approved timecard.

As a system Administrator, I am able to successfully edit the timecard in the future method with or without the Ops Edit Permission
But a manager still gets the error above even after giving the Ops Edit permission control.
I am not sure what else I'm missing in this case.
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Can you check in your approval process if this option is selected "Administrators OR the currently assigned approver can edit records during the approval process."

Comment: By default it is assigned to "Administrators ONLY can edit records during the approval process."

Comment: N.B. this question is about FinancialForce

Comment: yes, In the approval process the option Administrators OR the currently assigned approver can edit records during the approval process." is selected. The assigned approver is able to approve the timecard by clicking approve, but the error occurs when the future methods tries to update the approved timecard